# Netty and non standard TCP connections

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have 2 components, A and B, on different LANs with a Linux server between which acts as gateway for both LANs.

A sends TCP traffic to B using a gateway deployed on the public Internet. Therefore, no SYN is sent from A to B via the Linux server. However, C sends TCP traffic back to A using a local TCP connection (the gateway is not involved). By sniffing the traffic, I can see that C is not establishing a regular TCP connection (SYN) but starts by sending (SYN+ACK).

I'm using `iptables` on the Linux server to redirect locally the TCP traffic sent by C to A. Traffic is redirected to local port 9000.

However, I would also like to intercept this traffic, therefore I've built a simple Netty proxy which listens on port 9000. For some reason, Netty doesn't receive or ignore this traffic.

I wonder if Netty is able to manage the case of a SYN-ACK without SYN.

Any idea?

Comment: The TCP stacks handles it for sure. If I remove the REDIRECT rule from iptables, this special traffic is routed to A and everything works fine.

Comment: If the TCP stack handles it what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Your answer helped me understand that the fact the TCP traffic transits via the server doesn't mean it is handled by the Linux TCP stack but it is handled by the network layer. Therefore, I can only say the traffic is handled by the TCP stacks of the endpoints (A and B) but not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether the TCP protcool implementation stack in the kernel will manage it.

Netty won't even see it, whether managed by TCP/IP or not.

Netty isn't an implementation of TCP/IP. It is an API layered over the Java API, which is layered over the BSD Sockets API, and none of those is an implementation of TCP/IP either. It can't see any further into the network than calling `listen()` and `accept()` in this case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the kernel is able to route it. But if I want to intercept it, I will be working at the transport layer and the kernel will probably not be able to manage it. Assuming the only information my proxy uses to make decisions is the destination IP address (network layer), is it possible to write such proxy with Netty that works up to the network layer only?

Comment: Netty is not part of the transport layer. Netty is part of the application layer, along with Java and the BSD Sockets. API, and your code.

Comment: So I understand it can't be done with Java at all (maybe JNI can help)? If yes, a solution would be to use a kernel module that will take part of the routing?

Comment: JNI is part of Java, which is in the application layer. You need to get into the kernel by the sound of things.